# how to run Flash Player on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, flash

how can i run Adobe Flash on Windows XP? my XP has been hit by the Adobe Flash Time Bomb and only get the "adobe flash is EOL" error, instead of running flash, i tried [KuromeSan/FlashPatcher](https://github.com/KuromeSan/FlashPatcher/releases/tag/v1.7) and a few similar time-bomb-removers, but none of them were XP-compatible..

if you wonder why on earth anyone would want to run XP, i got some old servers whose Dell iDRAC/ HP iLO / Cisco CIMC requires old versions of Java Web Applet / Adobe Flash / IE web browsers to run, and i have a Windows XP VMWare VM for this exact purpose. got a problem with a "Cisco UCS C200 M2" server, whose CIMC GUI interface requires Adobe Flash to run.... and yeah i tried [Ruffle](https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle), unfortunately Ruffle's ActionScript3 support is very limited, and CIMC use ActionScript3, and Ruffle isn't compatible with CIMC -yet- (it may very well become compatible in the future as Ruffle's ActionScript3 compatibility improves, idk)

Comment: probably more suitable on [retrocomputing.se]

Comment: Which iLO versions need Flash, though? All I know is iLO4 used to require Java or .NET for the KVM feature – and the latest firmware actually has HTML5 KVM – but the rest of its interface was just standard HTML, no Flash. Everything else I've seen so far has been Java-only, not Flash-based... (I actually keep around a "portable" version of Java 1.6 for a DRAC5 system.)

Comment: @user1686 sorry i meant Cisco CIMC not HP iLO, but it's complicated because Cisco bought iLO from HP and just renamed it CIMC, CIMC and iLO are very similar, i think it's based in iLO4-something. anyway cimc firmware 1.4(3z09) bios version C200.1.3.2.0 (Build Date: 03/27/2011), requires both Adobe Flash and Java WebApplet. "Flash version 32.0.0.371" + "Firefox ESR 52.9.0" + "Java SE 6 U45" + "Windows XP SP3" is a functional combo :)

Comment: Ah, I see the Cisco UI in your screenshot... it doesn't really resemble iLO4 at all, though. (If anything, it reminds me of Dell's iDRAC5, but only slightly.)

Answer (score 2):

turns out that the last version of Flash without the time-bomb is version 32.0.0.371, and it's XP compatible, and it's available here https://archive.org/details/flashplayer_old (: problem solved
[image]